# read data from file, store in a python dict and search for values in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I had a text file with some information like this:

```
A , 12
B , 34
A , 54
F , 60
```

I want to read the file, and store the information in a python dictionary, like this: {'A':['12','54',...], B:['34',....]...} and so on. But I am stuck with how to search every A in lines. This is my tried:

```
    repo = {}
    infile = open('test10.log','r')
    lines = infile.readlines()[2:-1]
    for i in lines:
            module = ''.join(i.split(',')[:-1])
            time = ''.join(i.split(',')[1:]).replace('\n','')
            if not module in repo: 
                    repo[module] = time
```

Thanks for your help!.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is not such a data structure like `{A:{12,54,...}, B:{34,....}`. However:

```
repo = {}
infile = open('test10.log','r')
lines = infile.readlines()[2:-1]
for i in lines:
    module, time = [a.strip() for a in i.split(',')]
    repo.setdefault(module, []).append(int(time))
```

will give you a dict of lists:

```
{'A': [12, 54], 'B': [34], 'F': [60]}
```

Is this what you want?

Comment: Hmmm, why can I have the same output? Mine only shows `{'A': [54], 'F': [60]}`

Comment: I don't know why but I am running Python 2.7.2 and `lines = infile.readlines()[2:-1]` skips the first 2 lines and the last line so that was why I didn't get the same result ...

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use **defaultdict** from **collections** module:

```
from collections import defaultdict

repo = defaultdict(list)
infile = open('test10.log','r')
lines = infile.readlines()[2:-1]
for item in lines:
    module, time = [a.strip() for a in item.split(',')]
    repo[module].append(time)
```

If you `print(dict(repo.items()))` you should get:

```
{'A': ['12', '54'], 'B': ['34'], 'F': ['60']}
```

If you `print(list(repo.items()))` you should get:

```
[('A', ['12', '54']), ('B', ['34']), ('F', ['60'])]
```

See

- http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict
- [http://python.net/~goodger/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html#defaultdict](http://python.net/%7Egoodger/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html#defaultdict)

  for documentation about **defaultdict**